# Matlab - use find in range of indices

Tags: matlab

I often need to do searches in various portions of a vector but I don't want the indices based on the portion but on the whole vector. Is there a more formal way than doing this:

```
find(y(5:10))+5-1
```

Comment: You didn't tag the question with MATLAB, which is probably why it took a while for someone to comment.  I've added the MATLAB tag to your question while removing other relevant ones for future readership.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` in conjunction with a mask that tells `find` which indices you want to skip.  What you can do is declare a mask that is the same size as `y`, and place `false` in the locations that you don't want `find` to search for and `true` otherwise.  In this way, you don't need to offset the indices of `find` when you're done.  Once you declare this mask, search for the values you want with whatever Boolean condition you want to set up, and make sure you logical AND this result with your mask.

Something like this:

```
rng(123);
y = randi(10,20,1);
mask = false(20,1);
mask(5:10) = true;
ind = find((y == 10) & mask);
```

The above code sets a random generator seed to 123 so you can reproduce the results I am producing.  Next, we generate 20 random integers between 1 and 10, and create a mask that is the same size where we only want to search within locations 5 to 10 of the random vector.  I want to look for any instances within locations 5 to 10 that match the value of 10, so first search for `y == 10`, then logical AND this with your mask to only include those entries within the range you want.  `ind` should give you those indices that are with respect to the entire vector.

To see what `y` and `mask` are, here's what they look like:

```
>> y

y =

     7
     3
     3
     6
     8
     5
    10
     7
     5
     4
     4
     8
     5
     1
     4
     8
     2
     2
     6
     6

>> mask

mask =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Note that between locations 5 and 10, this is what `y` gives us:

```
>> y(mask)

ans =

     8
     5
    10
     7
     5
     4
```

As such, the value of 8 is from location 5, the value of 5 is from location 6 and so on.  I want to search for all values that are equal to 10, and so when we run the final statement with `find`, we get:

```
>> ind = find((y == 10) & mask);

ind = 

7
```

As you can see, we found the value of `10` located at location 7, which is indeed correct with reference to the entire vector.

Comment: You are the man. And I just change the mask to change the search range. It looks light enough. I wonder, is this some known technique or made up just for Matlab. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ahaha thanks! Actually I'm not sure if this is an accepted technique TBH. This is the first thing that came to me without adding the offsets like you did in your post.